# Remove Object in Firebase? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to loop through an object in my app and delete old messages after there are 30 messages already in the Database. Here is my code so far:

```
var ref1 = firebase.database().ref("chatRooms/" + rm + "/messages");
var query = ref1.orderByChild("time");

query.once("value").then(function(l) {
    l.forEach(function(d) {
      ref1.once("value").then(function(snapshot1) {
      var ast = snapshot1.numChildren(); // Getting the number of children
      console.log(ast);
      if (ast > 29) {
        d.remove();

      }
    });
  });
});
```

The only problem is that I receive the following error for each one:

> **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'**.

If anyone knows how to fix this, or knows of an alternative, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `d` is a `DataSnapshot`, which represents the value at a given location at some specific time. It cannot be removed directly.

But you can look up the location that the value is from and call `remove()` there:

```
d.ref.remove();
```

Full working (and simplified) snippet:

```
function deleteMessages(maxCount) {
  root.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var count = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      count++;
      if (count > maxCount) {
        console.log('Removing child '+child.key);
        child.ref.remove();
      }
    });
    console.log(count, snapshot.numChildren());
  });

}

deleteMessages(29);
```

Live code sample: http://jsbin.com/tepate/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I receive this error: SCRIPT5002: Function expected. ?

Comment: I'm also receiving this warning from Firebase in the console: **FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Function expected**.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem? It'll be easier to show you how to fix your code that way.

Comment: Thank you very much! The only problem I have now is that it erases the 29 most RECENT messages. Is there a way to order the children in reverse order so that this doesn't occur?? Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: If you do a search for questions about reversing the order in firebase queries, you will find that the topic has been discussed a lot already.

Comment: I keep looking, but I haven't found a solution. Could you link me to a page where it is discussed?